# Flutter Google Drive: download or read the contents of a file

Tags: flutter, dart, google-drive-api

I am trying to backup local database to google drive and restore it whenever user wants.
I have successfully uploaded file to google drive, now I want to read/download google drive file. I have found a way to get it done, but it is showing me errors. First it was showing "A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Media?'.". So, put as ga.Media at the end of the line and resolved the issue.

Please help me to resolve this error, I am stuck with this for like a month

[image]

```
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as ga;
const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'];
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart' as sign_in;
import 'google_auth_client.dart';


readFileContentFromGoogleDrive(String fileId) async {
    var client = await getHttpClient();
    var drive = ga.DriveApi(client!);
    print("FILE ID: ${fileId}");

    ga.Media? file = await drive.files.get(fileId, downloadOptions: ga.DownloadOptions.fullMedia) as ga.Media;

    List<int> dataStore = [];

    file.stream.listen((data) {
    dataStore.insertAll(dataStore.length, data);
    }, onDone: () async {
        Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory(); //Get temp folder using Path Provider
        String tempPath = tempDir.path; //Get path to that location
        File file = File('$tempPath/test'); //Create a dummy file
        await file.writeAsBytes(dataStore); //Write to that file from the datastore you created from the Media stream
        String content = file.readAsStringSync(); // Read String from the file
        print(content); //Finally you have your text
        print("Task Done");
    }, onError: (error) {
    });
}
```

I tried many ways but it seems google API has been changed, and didn't find solution. I have also searched for permission issue, but I think user is trying to access own file so it shouldn't be a problem. Basically, I am trying to backup local database to google drive and restore it whenever user wants.

Comment: It is a 404 error. That mean that the file was not found. Are you sure the file is there?

Comment: Yes, file is exist. You can see File ID in screenshot.

Comment: How do you get the file id?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I got sick. First I got file list using driveApi.files.list and then I passed fileId from it in above function. I checked file id in google drive it was same as shown in screenshot. So probably no issue of file doesn't exist in drive. this is file link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sCdYv9NA836qyLsyrfPFcaXtI7sId3II/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where do you use the scope for google login?